# Increase Mysql/PHP Query Speed

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables,one has 2 million and the other has 30 million records,
I need to compare the records on both tables but this is extremely slow.

can anyone offer suggestions on ways to increase the speed?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("DMBONE", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sucid where priority=''");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM bills_logic where month(tdate)=8 and  x1=".$row[0]."");
if($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
if($row1[0]==0)
{
echo $row[0]."  DEAD\r\n";
mysql_query("update sucid set priority='DEAD' where bid=".$row[0]."") or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo $row[0]."  ".$row1[0]."\r\n";
mysql_query("update sucid set priority='".$row1[0]."' where bid=".$row[0]."") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
}
?>


CREATE TABLE `sucid` (
 `bid` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `priority` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

    CREATE TABLE `bills_logic` (
 `bid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `num` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `stat` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `tdate` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `x1` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `amt` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '30',
 PRIMARY KEY (`bid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35214848 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

above are the create table statements for the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found the world's slowest way of doing a `join`. You may be happier to do it the old-fashioned way (but just fashionably enough to use `mysqli`):

```php
<?php    
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","database");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
     exit();
  }

  $sql = "update sucid
          left join (
            select count(*) as priority, x1 
            from bills_logic b
            where month(tdate)=8
            group by x1
          ) bg
          on bg.x1 = sucid.bid
          set sucid.priority = coalesce(bg.priority,'DEAD');" 

  if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    printf("I'm done already. This was fast, wasn't it?\n");
  } 
  else {
    echo "Something went wrong: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit();
  }

?>
```

You might want to add an index on `bills_logic.x1`, though it will not help too much here.

And you should really fix your columns, e.g. `tdate` should not be a `varchar(500)`. The update will fail completely if you have any row with an invalid date. Using correct datatypes prevents you from having invalid values. `num`, `stat` and `amt` sound like they could be `int` (or maybe `decimal`), `x1` maybe too. And your `priority`-column would also work as `int`, if you replace `DEAD` with `0`.

Comment: worked like a charm, I really need to brush up on my sql.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create indexes, particularly for the values that you are using to delimitate your searches. In your particular case, I would start by creating an index for the field **priority**.

For more info on how mysql deals with indexes take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible that you have a big big problem on it. The speed and query performance depends on:

1. Database schema table structure.
2. Machine hardware specs.
3. Your query structure.
4. table Indexes.

Hope all Database expert do not include the blob at the same table which is the primary table. this is the big problem of all database when we talk about a million of data to fetch on. Much better to separate the blob data always as  best practice.

This is just additional info, Hope it could help the others.